# InfoPath Drop Down list, loses data after trying to submit

Tags: sharepoint, infopath2010

I have a question about my InfoPath Form:

When I select a value from the first Drop Down list, the second one appears (it has a hide rule) and it has the values I configured in the InfoPath.

But when I select a value from the first Drop Down list and do not click on the second one, I get an error!

After this, I submit the form and the forms needs a value from the second Drop Down. So, after this message, I clicked in the second Drop Box, but all the values are gone.

If I exit the form, and open it again, the forms loads OK and if I repeat the same actions, the data of the second Drop Down list disappears again.

Comment: >> When I select a value from the first Drop Down list, the second one appears -- Where does what appear? >> But when I select a value from the first Drop Down list and do not click on the second one, I get an error! -- What error? When does it appear? Simply not clicking a drop down does not trigger an error. Please provide more detail. Is it a Browser or a list form? What rules are applied? Post a sample form. It is not possible to troubleshoot your problem with the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Teylyn! There are no error message! Just the drop box's data is gone after I pressed the button with the rule of submit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved guys!
I changed the button of Infopath, before it was reading the a rule for submit, now the button is a submit button!

Hope this can help someone!